Почему обработчик callback_data в telebot не вызывается при нажатии кнопки?
Пишу тг бота на Python с использованием библиотеки telebot. У меня есть кнопка "отправить" с callback_data, которая должна вызывать метод для публикации новости. Однако обработчик этой кнопки не вызывается.
Вот часть кода, связанная с генерацией кнопки:
def preview_news(self, news_items, chat_id):
    self.current_news = news_items
    for idx, news in enumerate(news_items):
        text = f"*{news['title']}*\n\n{news['description']}"
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        post_button = types.InlineKeyboardButton(f" Опубликовать {idx}", callback_data=f"post_{idx}")
        markup.add(post_button)
        self.bot.send_message(chat_id, text, reply_markup=markup, parse_mode="Markdown")

А это обработчик:
@self.bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data.startswith("post_"))
        def post_news(call):
            print("ping")

Попробовал добавить универсальный обработчик, но он тоже не вызывается:
def register_handlers(self):
    @self.bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
    def debug_callback(call):
        print(f"ping: {call.data}")

В чём может быть проблема? Как её решить?

Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример.
